# How restrict custom field with Paid Member Subscriptions (PMS)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use [Paid Member Subscription (PMS) Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-member-subscriptions/) to protect my content website.

If I protect my content, the shortcode like this:

```
[pms-restrict subscription_plans='21,22,23,27']
my content is protected
[/pms-restrict]
```

How use do_shortcode for this code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/files/<?php the_title(); ?>.epub">CLICK TO DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: did you try with do_shortcode ?

Comment: yes. I did try with do_shortcode.